# Show that if $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff for all $\alpha$, then $\prod X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff under the box and product topologies.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof? I am aware that there is a similar question posted elsewhere, but I need help with my proof in particular.

$\textbf{Note:}$ This is not homework.

> Show that if $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff for all $\alpha$, then $\prod X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff under the box and product topologies.

Let $(x_\alpha), (y_\alpha) \in \prod X_\alpha$ with $(x_\alpha) \neq (y_\alpha)$. Then, there exists an index $\beta$ such that $x_\beta \neq y_\beta$. Since $X_\beta$ is Hausdorff, we can pick disjoint open sets $U_\beta$ and $V_\beta$ such that $x_\beta \in U_\beta$ and $y_\beta \in V_\beta$.

Let $\pi_\beta : \prod X_\alpha \longrightarrow X_\beta$ denote the projection onto factor $\beta$. Then, $\pi^{-1}(U_\beta)$ and $\pi^{-1}(V_\beta)$ are disjoint sets which are open in both the product and box topologies, and contain $(x_\beta)$ and $(y_\beta)$, respectively.

Therefore, $\prod X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff under the box and product topologies.

Comment: To me, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.